# Can I make graphics in Python without importing a graphics library? If not, why?

Tags: python

I am learning  graphics and GUI in Python. I am curious to know how these modules like `pygame`, `tkinter`, `pyside` work on the backend. I opened their code but they are importing more and when I reached the more there's something like `def Window: --> None ....` Where is the code which is drawing a window on the screen? How can I get that code or how will I be able to make just a simple blank window?

Comment: Yes, you can do that. Will probably take you a few years and will not work on different operating systems, or even on different versions of your current OS, etc. The tools you are referring to most likely use c extensions for their internal code.

Comment: You need code written in C to make syscalls no matter what. If you don't import anything you don't have C extensions; it's an import to get dlopen to be able to call code written in C via ctypes.

Comment: You're likely looking at stub files, which just provide type information for IDEs and type checking tools, like those provided in https://github.com/python/typeshed

Comment: At some point, once you strip off all the Python magic, you're going to get to some C code that calls different low-level functions depending on operating system. In *pure Python* without using any libraries, you can't do it. You're going to have to factor through C somewhere down the line.

Comment: There are some exceptions for operating systems where one can communicate with the windowing system by just reading and writing to file-like objects, but in most cases you need sockets, and it's an import to get the `socket` library too.

Comment: Without imports you also don't have the `os` module so you can't retrieve environment variables, which means you also in a lot of cases can't figure out where the files or sockets you'd need to use to communicate to the windowing system _even are_.

Comment: With not importing anything i refer to not importing any modules used to draw graphics and GUIs.

Comment: Then you need to write them all yourself, which will (as I already said) take you YEARS to complete, more like decades most likely.

Comment: So the solution one might be expecting is to create an graphic module in a low level lang and then import or integrate that module in python and use it in an easier syntax. Am i Right?

Comment: That's what your existing graphics modules in Python _are_ -- wrappers around lower-level libraries like GTK or Qt or Tk or so forth.

Comment: Someone may have written a low-level X11 library in Python as an experiment or toy, but... it's not an easy task, and not something that makes enough sense to justify the massive time/effort expendature.

Comment: ..."may have" -- turns out someone _actually has_; see https://pypi.org/project/python-xlib/ and https://github.com/python-xlib/python-xlib

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Practically? Not really.

Each operating system has its own means of interacting with the graphical subsystem, and provides C libraries (with wrappers available for various languages) for communication with that subsystem.

If communicating with a C library (whether via `ctypes` or building a Python module in C) that's specific to graphics counts as "importing something graphics-specific", the practical, easy, maintainable approaches are ruled out.

---

#### Technically? Yes.

Except that some of those interfaces are abstracted in a way that *does* let Python reasonably communicate with them; a key example of this is X11, which supports communicating with the windowing system over a socket.

Mind, you won't write a high-performance game this way: X11 supports modern extensions that support shared memory for faster communication than what the traditional socket approach allows; but it'll let you draw a window.

See [python-xlib](https://github.com/python-xlib/python-xlib) as a demonstrative example of a *pure Python* graphics library; anything it can do, you could also do yourself inside your script.

Take its [`examples/draw.py`](https://github.com/python-xlib/python-xlib/blob/376703ebb0069cf01727e22a679590fc14ac0152/examples/draw.py) as a starting point, and run down all the non-standard-library `import`s -- if you folded all the imported code into your script, you end up with a script that's drawing graphics with no graphics-specific imports.